# How to find the memory address of the parameter(s) of a function

Tags: linux, memory, c, buffer

For context, I am attempting to exploit a buffer overflow as a practice exercise. I need to pass a parameter into a function via memory address. I have found the address for the function I would like to call and already managed to overflow it into the EIP register but I cannot figure out how I would pass it a parameter to use when it is run.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And how do you "overflow" the function with EIP? It is just an address which is pointing to a next command to execute. You call a function by assigning its address to EIP.
Which buffer you are overflowing? And for parameters - look at ESP.

Comment: I am overflowing EIP with the address to "system" as I am trying to call the system function. I found this address by running `x system` in GDB. I would like to pass arguments/parameters to that function when I call it from the EIP overflow. How would I go about finding where in memory the ESP register is? I have tried several times by just sending a ton of characters but I can never seem to get it to change when I check it using `info reg esp` in GDB when it stops due to seg fault.

Comment: ESP isn’t in memory, it’s a register. On 32-bit x86, parameters are passed by pushing them onto the stack.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You will need to study the function *calling convention* used by your target. It can vary by the combination of hardware architecture + operating system + programming language used. Since you are targeting a Linux system call, it uses C-style calling conventions (either 32- or 64-bit). Once you understand the calling convention, you will know how to arrange the function parameters into CPU registers and/or stack.